# python3 use of abstract base class for inheriting attributes

Tags: python

I am trying to use an abstract base class using the `abc.ABCMeta` . Here is the sample code -

```
import abc
class A(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self):
        self.v1 = 10
        self.v2 = 10

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def first_method(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.v2= 20

    def first_method(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = B()
    print("v1 =%d", b.v1)
    print("v2=%d", b.v2)
```

If I do not define `__init__` in `class B`, it would just take the values of `v1` and `v2` from the superclass A. But,I want to use the value of `v1` from the abstract class `A` and override the value of variable `v2`.  If I try to call `super.__init__(self)` it gives an error. Can someone please let me know the way to accomplish this? Thank you.

**UPDATE:**  Got the following error message with the above sample code:
`AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'v1'`

Comment: What does the error say :) ?

Comment: sorry, it says `AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'v1'`

Comment: I meant with `super().__init__(self)` included? It probably says `__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. Try without the `self` parameter, its already included in the `super()` call.

Comment: ha! you got it...   `super().__init__()` please post the answer so that i can accept :-)

Comment: You can pick Yaroslav's answer, no need to double post it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `super().__init__()` instead of `super.__init__(self)`.

Answer (score 0):

this should work.

```
import abc


class A(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):

    def __init__(self):
        self.v1 = 10
        self.v2 = 10

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def first_method(self):
        pass


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.v2 = 20

    def first_method(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = B()
    print('v1 = ', b.v1)
    print('v2 = ', b.v2)
```

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as Yaroslav, except it doesn't work with Python 3. (It would be correct for Python 2, but that's not what the OP is using.)

Comment: No, it doesn't. Compare `type(A)` in Python 2 and 3; Python 3 doesn't look at the `__metaclass__` attribute in the definition, so `A` isn't an abstract base class.

Comment: @chepner, you're right...now it is Python3 compatible

Comment: It is, but you aren't adding anything relevant that Yaroslav's answer doesn't already cover.

Comment: I did not notice it, until I posted.